# Android Studio: how to use streamscraper, to get shoutcast metadata

Tags: android, audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast, internet-radio

I'm a newbie in Android Development. I want to get metadata from **Shoutcast Server**, and found **streamscraper** to be the easiest one to use. But my problem is, I don't know how to use it. The homepage itself only showing something like in how to use it:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Stream;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Scraper;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.scraper.IceCastScraper;

    public class Harvester {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Scraper scraper = new IceCastScraper();
      List streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("http://host:port/"));
      for (Stream stream: streams) {
       System.out.println("Song Title: " + stream.getCurrentSong());
       System.out.println("URI: " + stream.getUri());
      }
     }
    }
```

Searched anywhere and found no project sample of how to use this. I hope one of you can post the code of how to use it, or make a tutorial for it.

Answer (score -2):

No need to use external libraries. The following pages give you:

```
Current song:     http://yourstream:port/currentsong?sid=#
Last 20 songs:    http://yourstream:port/played.html?sid#
Next songs:       http://yourstream:port/nextsongs?sid=#
```

An Android java class which prints the current song:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    
import java.net.URL;

public class NowPlaying {

    public void CurrentSong() {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mofosounds.com:8000/currentsong?sid=#");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the `nextsongs?sid=#`feature must be supported by the player of the stream.

Comment: @downvoter, explain? This is a perfect working example.

Comment: This isn't going to work on all streaming servers.  Most servers don't implement these endpoints, including most deployed versions of SHOUTcast.